# ¡Mantengamos los artículos del centro de ayuda actualizados!

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, traducciones, centro-de-ayuda

Aunque la iniciativa es [estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado), siéntase libre de hacer modificaciones si desea mejorar algo. Recibiré notificaciones y actualizaré el artículo del centro de ayuda asociado.

---

Muchas gracias a [@Pikoh](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15301/pikoh) por la traducción.

---

A principios de esta semana, mis colegas hicieron varias mejoras en el UX de cierre y actualizaron el centro de ayuda para representar la nueva interfaz.

¡Actualicemos los artículos del centro de ayuda en nuestra comunidad y agreguemos nuevas cadenas traducidas si es necesario juntos!

- <strike>✅[La lista de las nuevas cadenas está en Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yaL9EWFUmSZIdqXeydAG3yh5W6kthqSv4QHiS-ei7ns/edit). Por favor, añadid vuestras traducciones en [Traducir.win](https://traducir.win/). Por favor, tened en cuenta que aunque algunas cadenas en inglés han cambiado, puede que queramos usar las antiguas. Por ejemplo, razones de cierre.</strike>  (La traducción está hecha, pero podéis revisar las cadenas por si falta alguna o se puede mejorar alguna traducción)
- Se han editado tres artículos del centro de ayuda:

  - "[Reportes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)" ("[reportar publicaciones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4683/10)")
  - "[Emitir votos para cerrar y reabrir](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions)" ("[emitir votos para cerrar y reabrir](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4684/10)")
  - "[¿Qué significa si una pregunta está "cerrada" o "en espera"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)" ("[¿Qué significa si una pregunta está "cerrada" o "en espera"?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4685/10)

  ¡Intentemos mantenerlos actualizados juntos! Abajo, en las respuestas a esta pregunta están las versiones actuales de cada artículo. Las respuestas están marcadas como wiki. Si ves alguna oportunidad de mejorar o encuentras que algo se ha perdido, por favor no dudes en hacer una edición. Una vez que decidamos que hemos terminado, actualizaré el centro de ayuda.

Si tenéis alguna pregunta o sugerencia, por favor hacedla en los comentarios de este artículo. Gracias! =)

Comment: Nicolas, all the strings are translated (or should be) by now.

Comment: @Pikoh ¡Gracias! =)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Hi Nicolas, could you add the markdown of the new review queues from the help center? es.stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Hi @RafaelBautista! Thank you a lot for the ping! If I understand you correctly, [here are two new help center articles for first questions and first answers review queues](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4938/) (they linked in the table of contents at the end of the question).

Answer (score 1):

## [reportar publicaciones](http://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

#### ¿Que es un reporte?

Los reportes son una forma de llamar la atención de la comunidad sobre algún contenido inapropiado. Los tipos de reporte implementados actualmente son los siguientes:

1. Spam (es decir, publicidad indiscriminada)
2. Grosero o abusivo
3. No es una respuesta *(sólo respuestas)*
4. Reporte para cerrar *(sólo preguntas)*

   1. Pregunta duplicada
   2. Fuera de tema (con sub-motivos)
   3. No está claro lo que preguntas
   4. Demasiado amplia
   5. Principalmente basado en opiniones
5. Muy baja calidad (es decir, ninguna cantidad de ediciones puede salvar la publicación) (sólo nuevas publicaciones con puntaje 0 o menos)
6. Necesita la intervención de un moderador

   - Estas opciones no aparecerán en el menú de reportes hasta que se haya ganado una reputación de 50 (la cantidad requerida para comentar).

Si alguna vez estas confundido sobre el que razón para elegir para reportar, por favor sigue los siguientes enlaces:

- [Guía de uso para *spam* y *grosero/abusivo*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035)
- [Guía de uso para *no es una respuesta*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81392)
- [Guía de reporte *fuera de tema*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169824)
- [Guía de uso para *muy baja calidad*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606)
- [Guía para comentar reportes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365)

#### ¿Cuándo debo reportar?

Si pasa algo en nuestro sitio que te hace sentir incómodo o que, en tu opinión, claramente no pertenece aquí, por favor, ¡reporta y llama nuestra atención!

#### ¿Cómo puedo reportar?

Haz clic en el enlace <kbd>reportar</kbd> debajo de cualquier 
**publicación** y verás el cuadro de diálogo emergente que se muestra a continuación.

> [image: Reporte Publicación]

Pase el ratón sobre un **comentario** y haga clic en el icono en forma de bandera [image]a la izquierda y verás el diálogo emergente que se muestra a continuación.

> [image: Reporte Comentario]

#### ¿Qué pasa cuando reporto algo como spam o abusivo?

Los reportes de spam y abusivos están diseñados para eliminar automáticamente las publicaciones realmente perjudiciales a través de la colaboración de la comunidad.

- 3 reportes - la publicación es quitada de la página frontal.
- 6 reportes - la pulicación es bloqueada, borrada, y el propietario pierde 100 puntos de reputación.

#### ¿Qué pasa cuando reporto un comentario?

Además de traer el comentario a la atención de los moderadores, un número suficiente de reportes en un solo comentario hará que se borre automáticamente. El número de indicadores necesarios para su eliminación varía en función del número de votos en el comentario, así como el contenido del comentario en sí.

#### ¿Qué pasa cuando reporto algo como *necesita la atención de un moderador ♦* ?

Se te solicita que introduzcas un comentario explicando claramente cuál es el problema. Después de eso, estos reportes de moderador van a una cola especial de alta prioridad visible a todos los moderadores. (Los usuarios con el privilegio Herramientas de Moderador no pueden ver estos reportes.) Tomamos muy en serio los reportes de moderador; ¡puedes estar seguro de que todos están en seguimiento!

#### ¿Hay alguna manera de quitar reportes?

Si, mientras tu reporte está a la espera de ser manipulado, abre nuevamente el cuadro de diálogo de reporte, se visualizará la opción de retraer el reporte pendiente:

[image: redactar reporte]

No se puede levantar el mismo tipo de reporte dos veces en una publicación: por ejemplo, si te retractas de un reporte "spam", no serás capaz de levantar un reporte spam o un reporte abusivo en el futuro.

Retractar reportes sólo cuando estés seguro de que no hay necesidad de que la publicación se reporte, o si estas convencido de que se necesita un tipo de reporte más grave.

#### ¿Qué ocurre con los reportes?

Muchos reportes son manejados por otros miembros del sitio, que han ganado el privilegios de revisión. Reportes de cierre, no es una respuesta, y de muy baja calidad se manejan principalmente de esta manera.

Algunos reportes pueden ser manejados por el propio sistema: una cantidad suficiente de reportes tipo spam,  abusivos o en comentarios resultan en una acción inmediata (La eliminación de lo que sea que se reportó).

Los moderadores pueden intervenir para manejar reportes que no son manejados por miembros ordinarios del sitio web o el sistema.

Por último, las banderas que no se procesan en un plazo razonable de tiempo: reportes grosero/abusivos y de spam expiran después de 48 horas (y se retiran de inmediato si el mensaje se revierte a una revisión anterior a la que se encontraba reportada); reportes de cierre expiran después de entre 4-14 días (dependiendo de otros votos y vistas).

Puedes ver el resultado de tus reportes anteriores en cualquier momento haciendo clic en "reportes útiles" en tu perfil.

#### ¿Cuántas reportes tengo?

Cuando comienzas, tienes asignados **10** reportes por día. Este número puede aumentar a un máximo de **100** reportes por día:

- Se obtiene bonificación de reportes por cada 2000 puntos de reputación.
- Se le otorga una bonificación de reportes adicionales cuando se reporta correctamente - una bonificación por cada diez reportes útiles netos (reportes útiles menos reportes rechazados).

Answer (score 0):

## [emitir votos para cerrar y reabrir](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)

#### ¿Qué es el cierre de preguntas?

El cierre de una pregunta es un proceso de voto democrático donde la comunidad identifica preguntas que duplican el contenido existente, son irrazonables para responder en su estado actual o no son apropiadas para este sitio.

#### ¿Cuándo debería votar para cerrar una pregunta?

Las preguntas deben ser cerradas emitiendo votos de cierre si:

- Son suficientemente similares a preguntas ya existentes y se les respondería de manera idéntica.
- Son poco claras, demasiado amplias o de algún modo hacen difícil identificar el problema de manera que pueda ser abordada por los contestatarios.
- No están relacionadas a la temática del sitio, como se describe en el [Centro de Ayuda](/help/on-topic).

Ten en cuenta que una vez que ganes la reputación necesaria para votar el cierre, no debes reportar las preguntas a un moderador para que sean cerradas o se migren. Ahora es tu responsabilidad votar para ello. Véase también: *[How should my flagging change when I gain the ability to vote to close?](//meta.superuser.com/questions/3154/how-should-my-flagging-change-when-i-gain-the-ability-to-vote-to-close)*.

#### ¿Cómo puedo emitir un voto de cierre en una pregunta ?

El número actual de votos de cierre se mostrará bajo la pregunta, entre paréntesis, de la siguiente forma:

`cerrar (3)`

Si no hay  votos de cierre, simplemente aparecerá:

`cerrar`

Para emitir un voto de cierre –o simplemente para ver el recuento actual de votos de cierre y sus motivos– haz clic en el enlace 'cerrar' situado debajo del cuerpo de la pregunta. Aparecerá una lista con los motivos de cierre, con sus descripciones y el recuento actual.

[image: Ejemplo de diálogo de cierre]

Si deseas emitir un voto de cierre en este momento, usa el botón de opción para especificar el motivo para cerrar la pregunta, luego haz clic en el botón "Votar para cerrar". Si seleccionas “no relacionado porque...”, necesitarás seleccionar un sub-motivo adicional, explicando por qué la pregunta no está relacionada.

- Son necesarios **$CloseVotesNeededForClosure** votos de cierre para alcanzar el umbral de cierre (a excepción de las preguntas duplicadas, que pueden marcarse como duplicadas con un solo voto de un usuario que ha ganado una medalla de oro en una de las etiquetas actuales de esa pregunta, a menos que el usuario haya participado en la edición de las etiquetas de la pregunta).
- Puedes emitir hasta **$CloseVotesPerDay** votos de cierre por día.
- Los votos de cierre caducan sin tener consecuencias si el umbral no se alcanza después de varios días. Si la pregunta tiene por lo menos 100 visitas, los votos de cierre caducarán [después de **4** días](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56614/what-happened-here-voted-to-close-4-days-ago-but-no-close-votes-today/97594#97594)); en caso contrario, los votos de cierre caducarán [después de **14** días](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting). Cada nuevo voto de cierre restablece el temporizador, por lo que todos los votos de cierre deben tener al menos 4 o 14 días de antigüedad, respectivamente, antes de que se produzca su caducidad.
- Puedes retirar una votación de cierre en cualquier momento si la pregunta aún no ha sido cerrada haciendo clic en el enlace 'cerrar' debajo de la pregunta. Esto mostrará el cuadro de diálogo de cierre estándar, con el botón de envío cambiado a un botón de "Retirar el voto de cierre".

#### ¿Qué ocurre cuando una pregunta es cerrada?

Una vez que una pregunta es cerrada, no aceptará nuevas respuestas y las palabras `[en espera]` serán añadidas al título. Después de 5 días, si la pregunta se mantiene cerrada, la palabra `[cerrada]` se añadirá al título en su lugar.

Las preguntas cerradas pueden ser reabiertas mediante un proceso de voto similar. El número actual de votos de reapertura será mostrado debajo de la pregunta, entre paréntesis, de la siguiente forma:

`reabrir(3)`

Una descripción emergente mostrará el número de votos requeridos para reabrir.  Si no hay ningún voto de reapertura, simplemente aparecerá:

`reabrir`

Las preguntas pueden pasar por varios ciclos de cierre y reapertura, pero cada usuario individual puede emitir como máximo un voto de cierre y otro de reapertura por pregunta.

Las preguntas cerradas pueden combinarse con otra pregunta, migrarse a otro sitio de nuestra red o incluso eliminarse.

#### Alternativas al cierre

Si no tienes suficiente reputación para emitir votos de cierre, o has usado todos tus votos de cierre diarios, hay otras alternativas:

- Si la pregunta es duplicada, escribe un comentario con el enlace a la pregunta original.
- Si la pregunta tiene problemas serios (por ej. es spam u ofensiva), [repórtala en su lugar](/help/privileges/flag-posts).

#### Revisar votos de cierre y reapertura

Este nivel de privilegios desbloquea dos colas de revisión para preguntas que pueden necesitar ser [cerradas](/review/close) o [reabiertas](/review/reopen).

Cualquier publicación que tenga actualmente un voto de cierre activo *o* un [reporte](/help/privileges/flag-posts) de cierre aparecerá en la cola de revisión Votos de cierre. En esta cola, los usuarios pueden votar para cerrar la pregunta, editarla o recomendar dejarla abierta. Ediciones o un número suficiente de mensajes "Dejar abierta" la sacarán de la cola de revisión y comenzará de inmediato la caducidad de los votos de cierre. Si la pregunta recibe otro voto de cierre después de salir de revisión, volverá a entrar en la cola para su posterior revisión. Las preguntas con votos de cierre por ser duplicadas también enumerarán cada duplicado posible en una pestaña en la parte superior para facilitar la revisión.

Del mismo modo, la cola de reapertura contendrá cualquier mensaje que tenga actualmente un voto de reapertura activo. Los usuarios pueden votar para reabrir la pregunta, editarla (que incluye un voto de reapertura), o dejarla cerrada. Un cierto número de votos de "Mantener cerrada" volverá a enviar la pregunta fuera de la cola y comenzará el proceso de envejecimiento del voto de reapertura, y por supuesto, otro voto de reapertura volverá a ponerla de nuevo en la cola. Las preguntas que se editan dentro de los 5 días siguientes a su cierre aparecerán automáticamente en la cola de reapertura para su revisión. Las preguntas que han tenido una revisión agregarán una pestaña adicional en la parte superior para que se pueda ver rápidamente la revisión. Al igual que la cola de votos de cierre, las preguntas que se cerraron como duplicados seguirán enumerando los duplicados en las pestañas anteriores.

Answer (score 0):

## [¿Qué significa si una pregunta está "cerrada" o "en espera"?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

#### ¿Por qué algunas preguntas están marcadas "en espera"?

Las preguntas que necesitan trabajo adicional o que [no encajan en este sitio](/helpcenter/on-topic) pueden ser puestas en espera por miembros experimentados de la comunidad. Mientras las preguntas estén en espera, no pueden ser respondidas, pero pueden ser editadas para hacerlas elegibles para reapertura.

Las preguntas que son editadas dentro de cinco dias de haber sido puestas en espera son automáticamente agregadas a una cola de reapertura a revisión de la comunidad. Las preguntas que no sean reabiertas dentro de los cinco días cambiarán de `[en espera]` a `[cerrada]`.

Cada pregunta cerrada o en espera provee una razón que ayuda al autor original (u otros miembros de la comunidad) saber lo que ellos necesitan hacer para reabrir la pregunta.

Estas son las categorías de preguntas que pueden ser cerradas por la comunidad:

- [**Duplicada**](/help/duplicates)
   - el objetivo fundamental de cerrar preguntas duplicadas es para ayudar a las personas a encontrar la respuesta correcta al obtener todas esas respuestas en un lugar

  > Esta pregunta ha sido preguntada antes y ya posee una respuesta. Si esas respuestas no resuelven tu pregunta, por favor edita esta pregunta para explicar cómo es diferente o pregunta una nueva pregunta.
- **[Fuera de tema](/helpcenter/on-topic)** - cada comunidad decide cuáles temas específicos son y no son permitidos en su sitio.

  > Esta pregunta no parece ser sobre programación [dentro del alcance definido por la comunidad](/helpcenter/on-topic). Qué esta dentro y fuera de lugar no siempre es intuitivo, así que puede ser necesario  reescribir la pregunta para que encaje en el alcance de este sitio luego de revisar las guías de la comunidad.

  Considera editar la pregunta o dejar comentarios para mejora si crees que la pregunta puede ser reescrita para estar dentro del alcance.
- **No se entiende lo que estás preguntando** - algunas veces necesitamos más información para ayudar a resolver tu problema.

  > Por favor clarificar tu problema específico o proveer detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente qué necesitas. En su escritura actual, es difícil explicar qué es lo que preguntas exactamente.

  Edita tu publicación para ser más específico sobre lo que estás buscando, y asegúrate de resolver cualquier duda que otros usuarios indicaron en los comentarios.
- **Muy amplia** - si tu pregunta puede ser respondida por un libro entero, o tiene muchas respuestas válidas, probablemente es muy extensa para nuestro formato.

  > Existen muchas respuestas posibles o buenas respuestas pueden ser muy extensas para este formato. Por favor. Por favor agrega detalles para reducir el conjunto de respuestas o para isolar un problema que puede ser respondido en pocos párrafos.
- **La pregunta está buscando recomendaciones de libros,herramientas,librerías u otros recursos externos**

  > Estas preguntas tienden a recibir respuestas basadas en opiniones. Los listados de recursos externos no encajan bien en nuestro formato, y no se puede seleccionar una respuesta como aceptada ya que las mismas son todas opiniones.

  **Principalmente basada en opinión** - [las discusiones enfocadas en opiniones diversas](/help/dont-ask) son buenas, pero ellas no encajan bien en nuestro formato.

  > Muchas buenas preguntas generan un grado de opinión basado en la expertiz, pero las respuestas a esta pregunta tenderán a ser en su mayoría enteramente basadas en opiniones, en lugar de hechos, referencias o expertiz específico.

#### ¿Quiénes pueden poner las preguntas "en espera"?

Usuarios con la reputación $ReputationRequiredToClose pueden emitir hasta $CloseVotesPerDay votos por día. Cuando una pregunta llega a $CloseVotesNeededForClosure votos, es marcada `[es espera]`, y ya no aceptará respuestas. Aquellos usuarios pueden votar para reabrir las preguntas de la misma manera. Cada usuario solo puede votar para cerrar y reabrir una pregunta una sola vez. (Por ejemplo, si votas para cerrar una pregunta que está cerrada y luego es reabierta, no puedes votar para cerrarla nuevamente.)

Los moderadores pueden cerrar o abrir cualquier pregunta con un único voto.

Para más información sobre reapertura de preguntas, revisa ["¿Qué sucede si no estoy de acuerdo con el cierre de una pregunta? ¿Cómo puedo reabrir una pregunta cerrada?"](/helpcenter/reopen-questions)

#### ¿Por qué algunas preguntas están marcadas como "cerrada"?

Las preguntas están marcadas `[en espera]` por los primeros cinco días luego del cierre para alentar las ediciones y mejoras a la pregunta. Si una pregunta es editada por el autor original cuando está marcada `[en espera]`, será automáticamente puesta en una [cola de revisión](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues) para ser considerada para reapertura. Si la pregunta no es reabierta en de cinco días, el aviso de `[en espera]` cambiará automáticamente a `[cerrada]`. Funcionalmente, no hay diferencia entre una pregunta `[en espera]` y una `[cerrada]`; ninguna puede ser respondida hasta que sea reabierta, pero ambas permiten comentarios, votos y ediciones.