# Se solicita ayuda para traducir los artículos de las colas de revisión al español

Tags: discusión, traducciones, centro-de-ayuda

Muchas gracias a [@Juan M](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/juan-m) por la traducción.

---

Este año empezamos a trabajar en mejorar las [colas de revisión](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346901/improving-the-review-queues-project-overview). Un paso importante para ello es crear una nueva sección en el centro de ayuda para detallar las colas.

#### ¿Cuál es la importancia?

La mayoría de la información sobre las colas de revisión está guardada en los wikis de MSE. Estas publicaciones están muy detalladas y contienen todos los matices de cómo funciona una cola de revisión. A la misma vez, esto puede ser demasiado grueso para un principiante. La meta de esta iniciativa es crear un lugar donde podamos dirigir a los que deseen empezar a trabajar y comprender la mecánica del funcionamiento de las colas de revisión.

#### Se solicita ayuda para traducir los artículos de las colas de revisión al español

Hace unas semanas, creamos una primera versión de los artículos del centro de ayuda y [los publicamos en MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356120/274323) para recibir comentarios. Dado a los comentarios que recibimos, hemos finalizado los artículos y los hemos puesto en los centros de ayuda de cada sitio, incluyendo [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/review-queues).

He publicado las versiones más recientes de los artículos, pero en inglés, como respuestas a esta pregunta. Apreciaría mucho si me ayudaran con las traducciones al español. Nosotros creemos que solamente los usuarios pueden crear traducciones correctas que puedan ser entendidas por los otros usuarios de este sitio. En cuanto estos artículos estén listos, los pondré en el centro de ayuda como versión final.

Siéntanse con toda libertad para mejorar las traducciones existentes. Si es necesario, editen la redacción para que el texto se pueda leer naturalmente. Intentaré mantener el centro de ayuda actualizado con las revisiones más recientes en forma de respuestas a esta publicación.

#### Articulos del centro de ayuda para la cola de revisión

- [What are review queues?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4939/10)

  - [How do I use the First answers queue?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5344/10)
  - [How do I use the First questions queue?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5345/10)
- [Why was I suspended from the Review Queues?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4940/10)
- ✅[How do I use the Low-quality posts queue?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4941/10)
- ✅[How do I use the First posts queue?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4942/10)
- ✅[How do I use the Suggested edits queue?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4943/10)
- [How do I use the Close votes queue?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4944/10)
- [How do I use the Reopen votes queue?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4945/10)
- ✅[How do I use the Late Answers queue?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4946/10)

Comment: Where should we add the translations? Following the text in english, or should we replace it? I guess keeping the text in english would help others to improve the translation...

Comment: @Pikoh As you would prefer! Both works well. SOja users prefer replacing the text with the translation, SOru folks usually go with adding the translation bellow the text in English.

Comment: Nicolas, I think it is great that these documents are being updated. However, it is also worrying that the only presence of a CM in this site is to _ask_ the users to do something, while there are many other requests that are not being addressed. A once thrilling community needs some love from SO if it is still something SO cares for!

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Agree! Since the beginning of this year we started assisting all SE sites in a universal way: when mods of a site add [status-review] tag on a meta question, it escalates to the CM team automatically. Of course you can ping me if I can help you somehow, at the same time, in a long run [status-review] should work fine.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' [I found a link to the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348642/274323). I would appreciate it if you can translate the post or create a short version of it if you think it might be interesting to SOes users.

Comment: Oh, thanks. And yes, our moderators have been using this tagging system for some months now. There are several question with the [meta-tag:estado-en-revisión] right now. To me, the most important is the one asking for the close votes to lower from 5 to 3, which I have read is in the list of things to do in this Q4 2020.

Comment: Para revivir esta publicación: aún no se logró traducir todo el contenido. Y no está presente la ayuda para las nuevas colas de Primeras preguntas y Primeras respuestas (ya que fueron creadas luego de esta publicación). || To revive this post: not all the content has been translated yet. And the help for the new queues of First questions and First answers is not present (since they were created after this post).

Comment: Hola, deseo ayudar pero no estoy seguro con cuál artículo empezar o qué tan avanzado estén las traducciones, es la primera vez que me uno a algo de este estilo ¿Tomo un artículo y lo traduzco o por dónde debo empezar?

Comment: @Gutierrez ¡Hola! ¡Gracias por su interés! Sí, siéntase libre de tomar cualquier página sin traducir y traducirla directamente en la respuesta a esta pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

#### How do I use the Low-quality posts queue?

*Access earned at $Privilege-PostEditing reputation*
Posts entering the Low-quality posts queue have been [flagged as](/help/privileges/flag-posts)
problematic by users or recognized by
the system’s quality checks to be potentially low quality. This may
include:

- questions or answers that are very short, in the wrong
  language or gibberish.
- new or follow-up questions written as answers.
- answers that do not attempt to answer the question asked or contain
  only links and no explanation.
- comments entered as answers (“I have the
  same question” or “thanks for the great answer”).

It’s important to
remember that an incorrect answer is not “low quality” by our
definition. Incorrect answers should get a comment explaining any
issues or be downvoted, not flagged.

### Basic workflow

First, check to see if the post is a question or an answer; it will be labeled as "Question" or "Answer" at the top. The
majority of posts in this queue will be answers.

- Choose **Looks OK** for questions that are on-topic, sufficiently detailed
  and not too broad. Use this option for answers that answer the
  question as asked, even if they may be incorrect.
- **Edit** if the post is good quality, but you can improve the post to make it better. Avoid editing posts that should be closed or deleted, as it will remove the post from review.
- **Recommend deletion** or **Delete** if you think that an answer does not address the question at all, is link-only, or is incomprehensible. Do not vote to delete answers that are simply wrong. You may leave a comment explaining the issues with the answer, or choose one of the provided canned comments.
- **Recommend close** or **Close** if you think that a question should be closed (See [What does it mean if a question is](/help/closed-questions) “closed”?).
- **Skip** if you’re unsure about the post’s quality.

Some of the content of this page is adapted from information in our
[Meta Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029), which also contains more in-depth guidance if you are interested in reading more about this queue.

## Traducción

#### ¿Cómo utilizo la cola de Publicaciones de baja calidad?

*Acceso ganado con una reputación de $Privilege-PostEditing*
Las publicaciones que entran en la cola de Publicaciones de baja calidad han sido [reportados](/help/privileges/flag-posts) como problemáticos por los usuarios o reconocidos por los controles de calidad del sistema como potencialmente de baja calidad. Esto puede incluir:

- preguntas o respuestas muy cortas, en un idioma incorrecto o incoherentes.
- preguntas nuevas o de seguimiento escritas como respuestas.
- respuestas que no intentan responder a la pregunta formulada o que solo contienen enlaces y ninguna explicación.
- comentarios introducidos como respuestas (“tengo la misma pregunta” o “gracias por la gran respuesta”).

Es importante recordar que una respuesta incorrecta no es de "baja calidad" según nuestra definición. Las respuestas incorrectas deben recibir un comentario explicando los problemas o ser votadas en contra, no reportadas.

### Flujo básico de trabajo

En primer lugar, comprueba si la publicación es una pregunta o una respuesta; estará etiquetada como "Pregunta" o "Respuesta" en la parte superior. La mayoría de las publicaciones en esta cola serán respuestas.

- Elige **Se ve bien** para las preguntas que se ajustan al tema, son lo suficientemente detalladas y no son demasiado amplias. Utiliza esta opción para respuestas que respondan a la pregunta tal y como se ha formulado, aunque puedan ser incorrectas.
- **Editar** si la publicación es de buena calidad, pero puedes mejorarla. Evita editar publicaciones que deberían estar cerradas o eliminadas, ya que eliminará la publicación de la revisión.
- **Eliminación recomendada** o **Eliminar** si crees que una respuesta no aborda la pregunta en absoluto, es solo un enlace o es incomprensible. No votes para eliminar respuestas que son simplemente erróneas. Puedes dejar un comentario explicando los problemas de la respuesta, o elegir uno de los comentarios predefinidos proporcionados.
- **Recomendar cierre** o **Cerrar** si crees que una pregunta debe cerrarse (véase [¿Qué significa si una pregunta está "cerrada"?](/help/closed-questions))
- **Omitir** si no estás seguro de la calidad de la publicación.

Parte del contenido de esta página se adapta a partir de la información de nuestra [página de preguntas frecuentes (FAQ) de Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029), la cual también contiene una guía a mayor profundidad si estás interesado en leer más acerca de esta cola.

Comment: @padaleiana ¡Muchas gracias por la traducción!

Answer (score 1):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

#### How do I use the First posts queue?

*Access earned at $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues reputation*
The First Posts queue contains the first few posts created by new users, who may
not fully understand the best way to ask and answer questions, or
what's on- and off-topic on this site. The purpose of this queue is to
give special attention to users who may need to be educated on some
aspect of our model, and to posts that are more likely to need
improvement.

### Basic workflow

When reviewing, you may do one or more of several actions or you may do none. Perform all actions that you deem
necessary. For example, a question may be complete and on-topic but
need formatting help. In this case, edit to improve the formatting and - if you wish - upvote it before clicking "I'm done".

- Choose **No action needed** if the post requires no intervention.
- Select **I’m done** if/when you’ve completed any
  of the following:

  - **Vote** up or down.
  - **Edit** (or suggest an edit) if the
    post is clear and within guidelines, but could use some editing help to
    improve grammar, spelling, or formatting.
  - **Comment** (or upvote existing comments) to point out content
    that is missing or may need adjusting. These comments can be useful to
    both the post author and other reviewers.
  - **Flag** posts that are spam or rude, as well as answers that don't attempt to answer the question or are link-only.
  - [Trusted users](/help/privileges/trusted-user) may also **vote to delete** answers that don’t attempt to answer the question, are link-only, or are duplicates of other answers.
- **Skip** if you’re unsure about what to do.

One review from a user is enough to dismiss the task, so review
carefully to ensure that this question meets site expectations. Here
are some guidelines when reviewing and deciding which actions to take
on new posts:

#### For all posts

- If the post is spam or contains promotional links, flag it as "spam".
- If the post is offensive, flag as "rude or abusive".

#### For questions

- Check that the main part of the question is in the post itself and not hosted off-site. If there are links to other
  sites, the question should be written so that it makes sense even if
  the links break or change.
- The question should:

  - be clear.
  - have all necessary information required to answer it.
  - be on-topic for the site.
  - solicit fact-based answers.
  - show research.
  - be appropriately tagged.
- If appropriate, comment and ask for the missing information to narrow the
  scope of the question, or reword the question so it fits the site
  scope.
- If the question seems like a question you have seen before,
  check if the post is a duplicate.
- Upvote good, well-written questions
  to encourage new users.
- Sometimes a question will need to be closed,
  which can be done by [flagging](/help/privileges/flag-posts) or
  voting to close it. You can read
  more about when questions should be closed
  [here](/help/closed-questions).

#### For answers

- Check that the post author attempts to provide a focused answer, and not a simple comment or new question post.
- The post should be unique from other answers provided.
- The post should
  not have broken links or be exclusively made up of links.

For more information on how to edit effectively, please see our [Help
center article about editing](/help/editing).

Some of the content of this page is adapted from information in our
[Meta Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180030), which also contains more in-depth
guidance if you are interested in reading more about this queue.

## Traduccion

#### Como utilizo la cola de revisión para las primeras publicaciones?

*El acceso se obtiene cuando tengas **X** de reputación* (No se cuato es, se lo dejo a alguien que si)

Esta cola contiene las primeras publicaciones creadas por los usuarios nuevos, que puede que aun no entiendan la mejor manera de hacer y responder preguntas, o que no sepan que esta dentro y fuera de tema en este sitio. El propósito de esta cola de revisión es el darle atención especial a los usuarios que necesiten ser educados en algunos aspectos de nuestro modelo, y a las publicaciones que puede que necesiten mejoras.

#### Flujo de trabajo

Cuando estés revisando, puede que hagas una o mas acciones, o puede que no hagas ninguna. Tu toma todas la acciones que consideres necesarias. Por ejemplo, una pregunta puede ser completa, y estar en tema, pero puede necesitar ayuda para ser formateada. En este caso, edítala para arreglar el formato y - si así lo ves apropiado - dale un voto positivo antes de darle clic en **Terminé**.

- Elige **No se requiere ninguna acción** si la publicación no requiere de ninguna intervención
- Elige **Terminé** cuando tu hayas completado una o varias de las siguientes acciones:

  - **Vota** positiva o negativamente
  - **Edítala** (o sugiere una edición) si la publicación es clara y esta dentro de los lineamientos, pero necesita ayuda para mejorar la gramática, la ortografía, o el formato.
  - **Comenta** (o vota alguno de los comentarios que ya existen) para señalar algo que haga falta o que necesite ser ajustado. Estos comentarios pueden ser de ayuda tanto para el autor de la pregunta, como para las otras personas que la revisen.
  - **Reportar** publicaciones que son spam o abusivos, igual que respuestas que no pretenden responder la pregunta o que contienen únicamente un link.
  - **Los usuarios de confianza** *(Falta el link)* también pueden votar para borrar respuestas que no pretenden responder la pregunta, que contienen únicamente un link, o que son duplicados de otras respuestas.
- **Omitir** si no estas seguro de lo que vas a hacer.

Basta con una revisión para descartar la tarea, así que revisa con cuidado para asegurarte de que la pregunta cumple con las expectativas del sitio. Aquí tienes algunas pautas bajo las cuales te puedes guiar cuando revises y decidas que acciones tomar en las nuevas publicaciones.

#### Para todas las publicaciones

- Si la publicación es spam o contiene links promocionales, repórtala como **spam**.
- Si la publicación es ofensiva, repórtala como **irrespetuoso o abusivo**.

#### Para las preguntas

- Revisa que la parte principal de la pregunta este en la publicación y no en otro sitio web. Si hay links a otros sitios, mira que la pregunta este escrita de forma que tenga sentido aun si el link ya no funciona o cambia.
- La pregunta debería ...

  - ... ser clara
  - ... tener toda la información necesaria para responderla
  - ... estar dentro de tema
  - ... solicita respuestas basadas en hechos
  - ... demostrar que se ha investigado el tema
  - ... estar correctamente etiquetada
- Si es apropiado, comenta y pregunta por la información que haga falta para reducir el alcance, o cambiar la pregunta para que este dentro de tema en el sitio.
- Si te parece que has visto la pregunta antes, mira si es un duplicado.
- Vota positivamente las preguntas de calidad para animar a los usuarios nuevos.
- Algunas veces van a haber preguntas que necesiten ser cerradas, lo que se puede hacer **reportándolas** (Falta el link) o votando para cerrarlas. Puedes leer leer mas sobre cuando deben ser cerradas las preguntas **aqui** (Falta el link).

#### Para las respuestas

- Revisa que el autor de la respuesta intenta dar una respuesta enfocada, y no un simple comentario o una nueva pregunta.
- La respuesta tiene que ser única comparada con las demás respuestas.
- La respuesta no tiene que tener links que no funcionen, o estar completamente compuesta por links.

Para mas información sobre como editar efectivamente, por favor, mira el articulo en el **Centro de ayuda sobre la edición** (Falta el link)

Algo del contenido de esta pagina esta adaptado de la información en "[Meta Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180030)", que también contiene información mas en detalle si estas interesado en leer mas sobre esta cola.

Answer (score 0):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

#### What are review queues?

One of the ways that the community moderates the site is by reviewing posts that have been identified by users or the system as needing review to help determine whether the contribution is beneficial to the site. Once you have achieved $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues reputation, you have access to the first set of Review queues – and you’ll gain access to more as your reputation increases.

Review queues show you posts one at a time, so that you can evaluate what, if any, action is needed. Each queue is equipped with distinct options so that you may take appropriate action – in one, you may be looking at the first posts by new users. In another, edits suggested by lower-reputation users or assessing questions to determine if they should be closed or reopened.

Each queue has a specific purpose and each of the following Help center pages will help you learn more about how to review in each queue:

- [First posts](/help/review-first-posts) - $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues reputation. The First Posts queue contains the first posts made by users. These posts may need special attention because the users are not familiar with site quality rules.
- [Late answers](/help/review-late-answers) - $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues reputation. This queue contains answers that were posted much later than the question. Reviewing these posts makes sure that great new answers get seen and problematic answers get removed.
- [Triage](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-triage) – Stack Overflow only - 500 reputation. The primary goal of Triage is to quickly sort questions into groups: good as is, needs community editing, or should be closed/flagged.
- [Help and improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-help-and-improvement) - Stack Overflow only - 2,000 reputation. This queue lets you edit questions that were flagged in Triage as needing community editing.
- [Low quality posts](/help/review-low-quality) - $Privilege-PostEditing reputation. This queue contains posts that were determined to be of low quality based on a system-generated quality score and/or user flags.
- [Suggested edits](/help/review-suggested-edits) - $Privilege-PostEditing reputation. Editing other people's posts requires $Privilege-PostEditing reputation. When users without enough reputation submit an edit, their proposed changes go into this queue.
- [Close votes](/help/review-close) - $Privilege-CloseQuestion reputation. When questions aren’t a good fit for our format or scope, they need to be closed. Questions with active close votes or close flags show up in this queue so that others can review whether they should be closed.
- [Reopen votes](/help/review-reopen) - $Privilege-CloseQuestion reputation. When closed questions get edited, or if others disagree with the closure, they can be reopened. Questions with active reopen votes, as well as questions whose bodies have been edited during the first 70 days since they were closed appear in this queue.

Note: The First posts and Late answers queues do not exist on [Meta sites](/help/whats-meta).

## **Traducción**

#### ¿Qué son las colas de revisión?

Una de las formas en que la comunidad modera el sitio es revisando publicaciones que han sido identificadas por los usuarios o el sistema como necesarias de revisión para ayudar a determinar si la contribución es provechosa para el sitio. Una vez que obtengas $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues de reputación, tendrás acceso al primer conjunto de colas de Revisión – y obtendrás mayor acceso a medida que tu reputación aumente.

Las colas de Revisión muestran las publicaciones de uno en uno, para que puedas evaluar qué acción es necesaria, si es que se necesita alguna. Cada cola está provista de distintas opciones para que puedas tomar las medidas adecuadas - en una de ellas, puede que estés viendo las primeras publicaciones de los nuevos usuarios. En otra, ediciones sugeridas por usuarios de menor reputación o preguntas de evaluación para determinar si deben ser cerradas o reabiertas.

Cada cola tiene un propósito específico, y cada una de las siguientes páginas del Centro de Ayuda te ayudará a aprender más acerca de cómo revisar en cada cola:

- [Primeras publicaciones](/help/review-first-posts) - $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues de reputación. La cola de Primeras publicaciones contiene las primeras publicaciones hechas por los usuarios. Estas publicaciones pueden necesitar especial atención pues los usuarios no están familiarizados con las normas de calidad del sitio.
- [Respuestas tardías](/help/review-late-answers) - $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues de reputación. Esta cola contiene respuestas que han sido publicadas mucho más tarde que la pregunta. Revisar estas publicaciones asegura que estupendas nuevas respuestas sean vistas y que las respuestas problemáticas sean eliminadas.
- [Triaje](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-triage) – solo en Stack Overflow (inglés) - 500 de reputación. La finalidad principal del Triaje es ordenar rápidamente las preguntas en grupos: bien tal cual están, necesitan edición de la comunidad, o deben ser cerradas/reportadas.
- [Ayuda y mejora](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-help-and-improvement) - solo en Stack Overflow (inglés) - 2,000 de reputación. Esta cola permite editar preguntas que han sido reportadas en Triaje como necesarias de edición por parte de la comunidad.
- [Publicaciones de baja calidad](/help/review-low-quality) - $Privilege-PostEditing de reputación. Esta cola contiene publicaciones que han sido determinadas como de baja calidad basándose en en una puntuación de calidad generada por el sistema y/o reportes de usuarios.
- [Ediciones sugeridas](/help/review-suggested-edits) - $Privilege-PostEditing de reputación. Editar las publicaciones de otras personas requiere $Privilege-PostEditing de reputación. Cuando los usuarios sin suficiente reputación envían una edición, sus cambios propuestos van a esta cola.
- [Votos de cierre](/help/review-close) - $Privilege-CloseQuestion de reputación. Cuando las preguntas no se ajustan a nuestro formato o alcance, necesitan ser cerradas. Las preguntas con votos de cierre activos o reportes de cierre se muestran en esta cola para que los demás puedan revisar si deben ser cerradas.
- [Votos de reapertura](/help/review-reopen) - $Privilege-CloseQuestion de reputación. Cuando las preguntas cerradas se editan, o si otros no están de acuerdo con el cierre, pueden ser reabiertas. Las preguntas con votos de reapertura activos, así como las preguntas cuyos cuerpos han sido editados durante los primeros 70 días desde que fueron cerradas, aparecen en esta cola.

Nota: Las colas de Primeras publicaciones y Respuestas tardías no existen en los [sitios Meta](/help/whats-meta).

Answer (score 0):

#### Why was I suspended from the Review Queues?

---

*Learn more about [what the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work) are and how they work.*

Review suspensions are not penalties, but temporary holds on your reviewing privilege. The purpose of this is to give you time to learn more about how to review correctly. Poor reviews negatively effect the community and the site’s content. If you take incorrect action on multiple tasks, your reviewing privilege may be temporarily suspended and you won’t have access to the Reviews Queue during this time period.

If you are suspended, you will see a suspension message in the Review Queue navigational dropdown. A more detailed message will be available to you in the [Review Queue dashboard](/review) and in the queues. This message will remain for the duration of your suspension.

[image: Screenshot of the Review Queue dropdown in two states, first, during a suspension where the review suspension message ("Notice Review privileges suspended - Your review privileges are suspended until Jul 24. Click to learn more.") is visible but none of the review queues are and second after the suspension is over but the review message ("Notice Review privileges suspended - Your review privileges were suspended for 7 days. Click to learn more") is still visible.]

You may have been suspended between visits to the site. Although your suspension has expired, you will still be notified that the suspension occurred. Review and acknowledge the message and the notification will be dismissed.

### What can I do in the meantime?

Read the suspension notice carefully. Revisit the tasks that led to your suspension to understand the more appropriate action. Review resource links that may have been provided with your suspension. During your suspension, you will still have access to each queue’s Stats and History pages. If you have any questions about the review tasks that led to the suspension, post a question on Meta and use the `[review-suspension]` tag. In your post, be sure to include the following information:

- A link to the review that caused your suspension,
- An explanation of why you made the choice you did (particularly important if you feel the suspension is in error),
- A request to understand what the correct choice should have been and why.

In the future, take your time while reviewing and make sure each task is given adequate attention. If you're not certain what the correct action is, make use of the "Skip" feature and let someone else handle that review.

## Traducción

#### ¿Por qué fui suspendido de las Colas de Revisión?

---

*Aprende más sobre [qué son las colas de revisión y cómo funcionan](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work).*

Las suspensiones de revisión no son sanciones, simplemente no podrás ejercer tu privilegio de revisión temporalmente. El objetivo es darte tiempo para aprender mejor cómo revisar correctamente. Las revisiones pobres afectan negativamente la comunidad y el contenido del sitio. Si te equivocas en varias tareas, tu privilegio de revisión podría ser temporalmente suspendido y no tendrás acceso a las Colas de Revisión durante este periodo de tiempo.

Si estás suspendido, verás un mensaje de suspensión en el menú desplegable de Revisión. Habrá un mensaje más detallado para ti en el [panel de Colas de Revisión](/review) y en las colas. Este mensaje permanecerá hasta que tu suspensión acabe.

[image: Captura de pantalla del menú de las colas de revisión en dos estados, primero, durante una suspensión con el mensaje ("Notice Review privileges suspended - Your review privileges are suspended until Jul 24. Click to learn more.") visible pero ninguna de las colas de revisión y el segundo después de que la suspensión terminó pero el mensaje de revisión ("Notice Review privileges suspended - Your review privileges were suspended for 7 days. Click to learn more") todavía está visible.]

Podrías haber sido suspendido entre visitas al sitio. Aunque tu suspensión haya expirado, también serás notificado sobre ella. Revisa y   acepta el mensaje para que la notificación desaparezca.

### ¿Qué puedo hacer mientras tanto?

Lee el aviso cuidadosamente. Vuelve a visitar las tareas que provocaron tu suspensión para entender la acción más apropiada. Revisa los enlaces  que pudieron haber sido incluidos con tu suspensión. Durante tu suspensión, todavía tendrás acceso a las páginas de Estadísticas e Historial de cada cola. Si tienes alguna pregunta sobre las tareas de revisión que te llevaron a la suspensión, haz una pregunta en Meta con la etiqueta `[review-suspension]`. Asegúrate de incluir la siguiente información en la publicación:

- Un enlace a la revisión que causó tu suspensión,
- Una explicación de por qué tomaste la decisión que tomaste (particularmente importante si crees que la suspensión fue un<sup>1</sup> error),
- Una petición para entender cuál habría sido la decisión correcta y por qué.

En el futuro, tómate tu tiempo para revisar y asegúrate de darle la atención adecuada a cada tarea. Si no estás seguro sobre cuál es la decisión correcta, usa el botón de "Omitir" y deja que alguien más se encargue de esa revisión.

---

> <sup>1</sup> En el texto original dice *in* (en) pero interpreté que lo correcto es *an* (un).

Answer (score 0):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

#### How do I use the Suggested edits queue?

*Access earned at $Privilege-PostEditing reputation*
The primary purpose of the Suggested edits queue is to review edits contributed by users who have less than
$Privilege-PostEditing reputation and determine if the suggested edits
are beneficial to the post. Suggested edits should focus on improving
grammar, spelling, and formatting, all while maintaining the author’s
original intent.

For users with $Privilege-ApproveTagWikiEdits reputation, you may also see tag wiki edit suggestions in this queue. For more information about handling these reviews, see the [approve tag wiki edits](/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) privilege page.

### Basic workflow

Start by reading the edit summary and looking at the differences between the original post and the edit. Be sure to check
the title (and tags, if a question) to see if they were edited, and
check the comments section for any information that the author may
have included only in comments.

- **Approve** if the edit improves the post and doesn’t need any additional edits.
- **Improve edit** if the edit is good but incomplete, and use the edit window to fix any outstanding issues.
- **Reject** if the edit is unnecessary, destructive, or counter to the
  original author’s intent.
- **Reject and edit** if the suggested edit makes
  the post worse or doesn’t solve critical issues with the post. Then add
  your own edit - this will open an edit window allowing you to improve
  the post.
- **Skip** if you’re unsure whether the post was improved or not

### Common reasons to Approve

- Adds additional information or clarifies existing answer.
- Improves grammar, spelling or formatting of the post
  or other minor mistakes.
- Edits in information found in comments.
- Updates an answer if more information is available or something has
  changed.
- Adds links to sources or citations.

### Common reasons to Reject

When rejecting an edit, you’ll need to choose a rejection reason.
These are a good outline for the reasons you may need to reject a
suggested edit:

- Spam or vandalism

  - adds irrelevant or unattributed promotional links or
    mentions of products.
  - damages or destroys the content of the post.
- No improvement whatsoever

  - changes to content or formatting that are
    unnecessary or make the post more confusing.
  - changes to grammar,
    spelling,  or style that are unnecessary.
- Irrelevant tags

  - tags should
    clearly indicate the subject of the question; reject edits that add
    tags that are tangential or incorrect.
- Clearly conflicts with author’s
  intent

  - changes a post to say the opposite, or something very different
    from what the original post read.
- Attempt to reply

  - introduces a request for clarification or question to the post’s author that should have been a comment or answer.
- Causes harm

  - This reason can be used in cases where a suggestion should be prevented but none of the above or several of the above apply. You should explain why you are rejecting the suggestion so that other reviewers can understand your action.

Some of the content of this page is adapted from information in our
[Meta Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155539), which also contains more in-depth guidance if
you are interested in reading more about this queue.

## Traducción

#### ¿Cómo utilizo la cola de Ediciones sugeridas?

*Acceso ganado con una reputación de $Privilege-PostEditing*
El propósito principal de la cola de Ediciones sugeridas es revisar las ediciones aportadas por los usuarios que tienen una reputación de menos de $Privilege-PostEditing y determinar si las ediciones sugeridas son beneficiosas para la publicación. Las ediciones sugeridas deben centrarse en mejorar la gramática, la ortografía y el formato, manteniendo la intención original del autor.

Para los usuarios con reputación de $Privilege-ApproveTagWikiEdits, también pueden ver sugerencias de ediciones de wikis de etiqueta en esta cola. Para obtener más información sobre cómo manejar estas revisiones, consulta la página de privilegio de [aprobación de wikis de etiqueta](/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits).

### Flujo básico de trabajo

Comienza leyendo el resumen de la edición y observando las diferencias entre la publicación original y la edición. Asegúrate de revisar el título (y las etiquetas, si es una pregunta) para ver si fueron editados, y revisa la sección de comentarios para ver si hay alguna información que el autor haya incluido sólo en los comentarios.

- **Aprobar** si la edición mejora la publicación y no necesita ninguna edición adicional.
- **Mejorar edición** si la edición es buena pero incompleta; luego usa la ventana de edición para arreglar cualquier problema pendiente.
- **Rechazar** si la edición es innecesaria, destructiva, o contraria a la
  la intención del autor original.
- **Rechazar y editar** si la edición sugerida empeora la publicación o no resuelve los problemas críticos con la publicación. Luego agrega tu propia edición - esto abrirá una ventana de edición que te permitirá mejorar la publicación.
- **Omitir** si no estás seguro de si la publicación fue mejorada o no.

### Razones comunes para Aprobar

- Se agrega información adicional o clarifica la respuesta existente.
- Se mejora la gramática, la ortografía o el formato de la publicación u otros errores menores.
- Se edita según la información encontrada en los comentarios.
- Se actualiza una respuesta si hay más información disponible o si algo ha cambiado.
- Se añade enlaces a fuentes o citas.

### Razones comunes para Rechazar

Cuando rechaces una edición, tendrás que elegir una razón de rechazo. A continuación se describen las razones por las que puedes rechazar una edición sugerida:

- Contenido no deseado o vandalismo

  - añade enlaces o menciones promocionales irrelevantes o no atribuidas a los productos.
  - daña o destruye el contenido de la publicación.
- Sin ningún tipo de mejora

  - cambios en el contenido o el formato que son innecesarios o que hacen a la publicación más confusa.
  - cambios en la gramática, la ortografía o el estilo que son innecesarios.
- Etiquetas irrelevantes

  - las etiquetas deben indicar claramente el tema de la pregunta; rechaza las ediciones que añadan etiquetas tangenciales o incorrectas.
- Claramente en conflicto con la intención del autor

  - cambia una publicación para decir lo contrario, o algo muy diferente de lo que se lee de la publicación original.
- Intento de respuesta

  - introduce una solicitud de aclaración o pregunta al autor de la publicación que debería haber sido un comentario o una respuesta.
- Causa daño

  - Este motivo puede ser utilizado en casos donde una sugerencia de edición debe ser impedida pero no se aplica ninguna de las anteriores o varias de las anteriores. Debes explicar por qué rechazas la sugerencia para que otros revisores puedan entender tu acción.

Parte del contenido de esta página se adapta a partir de la información de nuestra [página de preguntas frecuentes (FAQ) de Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155539), la cual también contiene una guía a mayor profundidad si estás interesado en leer más acerca de esta cola.

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I use the Close votes queue?

*Access earned at $Privilege-CloseQuestion reputation*

The Close votes  queue includes questions that other users have flagged as needing to  be closed. Before reviewing in this queue, you should be familiar with what sorts of questions should and should not be closed. To find that information, see the following two pages:

- [Closed question help article](/help/closed-questions) is a network-wide guide for the primary reasons questions should be closed. This generally happens when a question:

  - is a [duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) of an existing question on the site.
  - needs additional details or clarity to be answered.
  - needs to be more focused, as the existing question is too broad.
  - is an opinion-based question that doesn’t have an objectively correct answer.
- [On topic article](/help/on-topic) is a site-specific guide to what types of questions are on and off topic on this site. This page will differ on each site on the Network.

### Basic workflow

At the top of the review task page, you’ll find the reasons others flagged or voted the question to be closed, but if you disagree, you may choose a different option. The close reason that gets the most votes will be indicated on the post if it is closed. Review the question content completely and then make a decision from one of the options:

- **Close** the question if it is a duplicate, lacks sufficient detail,
  needs to be narrowed in scope, is opinion based, is off topic, or if
  it meets one of the other community-specific reasons to close. Choose
  the applicable close reason based on your assessment. You also have
  the option to enter a custom reason if none of the existing ones
  apply.
- **Leave open** if none of the above is the case.
- **Edit** should be reserved for when the question is close-worthy as written, but when you believe you can rescue the question to make it fit the scope. This may mean adding in details the asker left in comments or making slight adjustments to an opinion-based question so that it's objective. Don’t make minor edits if the question would be closed even with these changes, as it will remove the question from review.
- **Skip** any time you’re not certain - don’t be afraid to use the skip button! Focus on reviewing posts you’re certain of rather than ones you need to guess how to handle.

**Tip:** You may want to restrict which questions you are shown to subjects you are familiar with by filtering reviews by tags you have experience in. You can do this by clicking “Filter” in the top section of a review task. When in doubt, choose Skip.

[image: Close votes filters]

Note: If you choose two tags, you will find all reviews with one or both tags. Filters will not restrict to reviews with both tags only.

Some of the content of this page is adapted from information in our [Meta Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180032), which also contains more in-depth guidance if you are interested in reading more about this queue.

## Traducción

#### ¿Cómo utilizo la cola de Votos de cierre?

*Acceso ganado con una reputación de $Privilege-CloseQuestion*

La cola de Votos de cierre incluye preguntas que otros usuarios han reportado como que necesitan ser cerradas. Antes de revisar en esta cola, debes estar familiarizado con qué tipos de preguntas deben o no ser cerradas. Para encontrar esta información, consulta las siguientes dos páginas:

- [El artículo de ayuda de pregunta cerrada](/help/closed-questions) es una guía en toda la red sobre las principales razones por las que deben cerrarse las preguntas. Esto generalmente sucede cuando la pregunta:

  - es un [duplicado](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) de una pregunta existente en el sitio.
  - necesita detalles o aclaraciones para ser respondida.
  - necesita estar más enfocada, ya que la pregunta actual es demasiado amplia.
  - es una pregunta basada en opiniones que no tiene una respuesta objetivamente correcta.
- [El artículo sobre la temática<sup>1</sup>](/help/on-topic) es una guía específica del sitio de qué tipos de preguntas están o no en la temática del sitio. Esta página diferirá en cada sitio de la Red.

### Flujo básico de trabajo

En la parte superior de la página de la tarea de revisión, encontrarás las razones por las que otros reportaron o votaron la pregunta para que se cerrara, pero si no estás de acuerdo, puedes elegir una opción diferente. La razón de cierre que obtenga más votos se indicará en la publicación si se cierra. Revisa el contenido de la pregunta por completo y luego decídete por una de las opciones:

- **Cerrar** la pregunta si es un duplicado, carece de suficientes detalles, es necesario reducir su alcance, es basada en opiniones, está fuera de tema, o si cumple una de las otras razones específicas de la comunidad para cerrar. Elige el motivo de cierre aplicable según tu evaluación. También tienes la opción de ingresar un motivo personalizado si ninguna de las existentes aplica.
- **Dejar abierta** si ninguno de los anteriores es el caso.
- **Editar** debe reservarse para cuando la pregunta merece ser cerrada tal como está escrita, pero cuando crees que puedes rescatarla para que se ajuste al alcance. Esto puede significar añadir detalles que el autor de la pregunta haya dejado en los comentarios o hacer ligeros ajustes a una pregunta basada en opiniones para que sea objetiva. No realices modificaciones menores si la pregunta se cerraría incluso con estos cambios, ya que la pregunta se eliminará de la revisión.
- **Omitir** siempre que no estés seguro - ¡no tengas miedo de usar el botón de omitir! Concéntrate en revisar las publicaciones de las que estés seguro, en lugar de las que tienes que adivinar cómo manejarlas.

**Consejo:** Es posible que desees restringir las preguntas que se te muestran a temas con los que estés familiarizado filtrando las tareas por etiquetas en las que tienes experiencia. Puedes hacerlo haciendo clic en “Filtrar” en la parte superior de la página de una tarea de revisión. Ante la duda, elige Omitir<sup>2</sup>.

[image: Filtros de votos de cierre]

Nota: Si escoges dos etiquetas, encontrarás todas las revisiones con una o ambas etiquetas. Los filtros no se limitarán solo las revisiones con ambas etiquetas.

Parte del contenido de esta página se adapta a partir de la información de nuestra [página de preguntas frecuentes (FAQ) de Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180032), la cual también contiene una guía a mayor profundidad si estás interesado en leer más acerca de esta cola.

---

> <sup>1</sup> Sugerencias son bienvenidas en cuanto a la palabra "temática", ya que pareciera ser el término más cercano a *On topic*. Si existe un término más acorde, mejor.
> <sup>2</sup> No hay ningún botón de Omitir... ¿Está desactualizado?

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I use the Reopen votes queue?

*Access earned at $Privilege-CloseQuestion reputation*
Any closed question that has received one reopen vote gets added to this queue,
as well as any question edited within 70 days since its closure.
Before reviewing in this queue, you should be familiar with what sorts
of questions should and should not be closed. To find that
information, see the following two pages:

- [Closed question help article](/help/closed-questions) is a
  network-wide guide for the primary reasons questions should be closed.
  This generally happens when a question:

  - is a duplicate of an existing question on the site.
  - needs additional details or clarity to be answered.
  - needs to be more focused, as the existing question is too broad.
  - is an opinion-based question that doesn’t have an objectively correct answer.
- [On topic article](/help/on-topic) is a site-specific guide to
  what types of questions are on and off topic on this site. This page
  will differ on each site on the Network.

### Basic workflow

Evaluate the question as it is now. Review any edits that may have been made after the question was closed and any comments
on the question. If edits were made but are insufficient to reopen the
question, consider leaving a comment explaining why.

- **Leave closed** if close reason(s) still apply. Do not reopen if the
  specific reason for closure no longer applies, but the question should
  still be closed. Consider leaving a comment to explain why the question should remain closed, particularly if the reason is different than what appears in the banner.
- **Edit and reopen** if you can resolve issues with the
  question yourself, and these edits are sufficient for the post to be
  reopened. Avoid making minor edits that don’t impact whether the post
  should be reopened.
- **Reopen** if issues with the question have been
  resolved, or if it was incorrectly closed.
- **Skip** if you're not sure
  whether the question should be reopened.

**Tip:** You may want to restrict which questions you are shown to subjects you are familiar with by filtering reviews by tags you have
experience in. You can do this by clicking “Filter” in the top section
of a review task. When in doubt, choose Skip.

[image: Reopen votes filter]

Some of the content of this page is adapted from information in our
[Meta Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180450), which also contains more in-depth
guidance if you are interested in reading more about this queue.

## Traducción

#### ¿Cómo utilizo la cola de Votos de reapertura?

*Acceso ganado con una reputación de $Privilege-CloseQuestion*

Cualquier pregunta cerrada que haya recibido un voto de reapertura se añade a esta cola, así como cualquier pregunta editada en los 70 días posteriores a su cierre. Antes de revisar en esta cola, debes estar familiarizado con qué tipos de preguntas deben o no ser cerradas. Para encontrar esta información, consulta las siguientes dos páginas:

- [El artículo de ayuda de pregunta cerrada](/help/closed-questions) es una guía en toda la red sobre las principales razones por las que deben cerrarse las preguntas. Esto generalmente sucede cuando la pregunta:

  - es un duplicado de una pregunta existente en el sitio.
  - necesita detalles o aclaraciones para ser respondida.
  - necesita estar más enfocada, ya que la pregunta actual es demasiado amplia.
  - es una pregunta basada en opiniones que no tiene una respuesta objetivamente correcta.
- [El artículo sobre la temática<sup>1</sup>](/help/on-topic) es una guía específica del sitio de qué tipos de preguntas están o no en la temática del sitio. Esta página diferirá en cada sitio de la Red.

### Flujo básico de trabajo

Evalúa la pregunta tal como está ahora. Revisa cualquier modificación que se haya hecho después de que la pregunta haya sido cerrada y cualquier comentario sobre la pregunta. Si se han realizado modificaciones pero no son suficientes como para reabrir la pregunta, considera dejar un comentario explicando por qué.

- **Dejar cerrada** si los motivos de cierre aún aplican. No la reabras si la razón específica para el cierre ya no aplica pero la pregunta debe aún permanecer cerrada. Considera dejar un comentario explicando por qué la pregunta debe permanecer cerrada, particularmente si el motivo es diferente al que aparece en el banner.
- **Editar y reabrir** si tú mismo puedes resolver los problemas de la publicación, y estas ediciones son suficientes para la publicación para ser reabierta. Evita realizar ediciones menores que no afecten si la publicación debe reabrirse.
- **Reapertura** si los problemas en la pregunta se han resuelto, o ha sido cerrada incorrectamente.
- **Omitir** si no estás seguro de que se deba reabrir la pregunta.

**Consejo:** Es posible que desees restringir las preguntas que se te muestran a temas con los que estés familiarizado filtrando las tareas por etiquetas en las que tienes experiencia. Puedes hacerlo haciendo clic en “Filtrar” en la parte superior de la página de una tarea de revisión. Ante la duda, elige Omitir<sup>2</sup>.

[image: Filtros de votos de reapertura]

Parte del contenido de esta página se adapta a partir de la información de nuestra [página de preguntas frecuentes (FAQ) de Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180450), la cual también contiene una guía a mayor profundidad si estás interesado en leer más acerca de esta cola.

---

> <sup>1</sup> Sugerencias son bienvenidas en cuanto a la palabra "temática", ya que pareciera ser el término más cercano a *On topic*. Si existe un término más acorde, mejor.
> <sup>2</sup> No hay ningún botón de Omitir... ¿Está desactualizado?

Answer (score 0):

[estado-completado](/questions/tagged/estado-completado)

#### How do I use the Late Answers queue?

*Access earned at $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues reputation*
The Late Answers queue contains answers that were posted by new users much
later than when the question was asked. Late answers tend to be seen
by fewer people than answers posted soon after the question was asked,
so the review queue helps ensure that these answers meet the same
quality standards as all other answers.

While many late answers are merely saying “Thanks!” or are attempts to
ask follow-up questions and should be deleted, in other cases it may
require specific knowledge of the topic. If you’re unsure whether the
answer actually attempts to answer the question, use the “Skip”
option.

### Basic workflow

When reviewing, you may do one or more of several actions or you may do none. Perform all actions that you deem
necessary. For example, an answer may be complete and do a good job of
answering the question, but need formatting help. In this case, edit to
improve the formatting and - if you wish - upvote it before clicking "I'm done".

- Choose **No action needed** if the answer requires no intervention
- Select **I’m done** if/when
  you’ve completed any of the following:

  - **Vote** up or down.
  - **Edit** (or
    suggest an edit) if the answer is clear and within guidelines, but
    could use some editing help to improve grammar, spelling, or
    formatting.
  - **Comment** to point out content that is missing or may need
    adjusting. These comments can be useful to both the post author and
    other reviewers.
  - **Flag** posts that are spam or rude, as well as answers that don't attempt to answer the question or are link-only.
  - [Trusted users](/help/privileges/trusted-user) may also **Delete** answers that don’t attempt to answer the question, are
    link-only, or are duplicates of other answers.
- **Skip** if you’re unsure about what to do

### Common Late answers

- Spam or self-promotion

  - If the answer meets the [description for acceptable self-promotion](/help/promotion), add a
    comment mentioning this to reduce the chance of other reviewers
    marking it spam. If it does not, add a comment linking to the help
    center article and encourage the author to edit the post to meet our
    guidelines. If it unequivocally looks like spam, flag it as such.
- Non-answers

  - Answers thanking the author of the question or one of its
    answers, asking a new question, stating that they have the same problem, or asking for clarification from the author. These should be deleted.

For more information on how to edit effectively, please see our [Help center article about editing](/help/editing).

Some of the content of this page is adapted from information in our
[Meta Stack Exchange FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180031), which also contains more in-depth
guidance if you are interested in reading more about this queue.

## **Traducción**

#### ¿Cómo utilizo la cola de Respuestas tardías?

*Acceso ganado con una reputación de $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues*
La cola de Respuestas tardías contiene respuestas que han sido publicadas por nuevos usuarios mucho más tarde que cuando se ha formulado la pregunta. Las respuestas tardías tienden a ser vistas por menos personas que las respuestas publicadas poco después de que se haya hecho la pregunta, por lo que la cola de revisión ayuda a asegurar que estas respuestas cumplan con los mismos estándares de calidad que todas las demás respuestas.

Si bien muchas respuestas tardías se limitan a decir “¡Gracias!” o son intentos de hacer preguntas de seguimiento y deben ser eliminadas, en otros casos puede ser necesario un conocimiento específico del tema. Si no estás seguro de si la respuesta realmente intenta responder a la pregunta, utiliza la opción “Omitir”.

### Flujo básico de trabajo

Al revisar, puedes o realizar una o más de varias acciones o no realizar ninguna. Haz todas las acciones que consideres necesarias. Por ejemplo, una respuesta puede ser completa y hacer un buen trabajo al responder la pregunta, pero necesita ayuda con el formato. En este caso, edítala para mejorar el formato y, si lo deseas, vota a favor antes de hacer clic en "Terminé".

- Elige **No se requiere ninguna acción** si la respuesta no requiere de intervención.
- Selecciona **Terminé** si/cuando has completado cualquiera de lo siguiente:

  - **Votar** a favor o en contra.
  - **Editar** (o sugerir una edición) si la respuesta es clara y dentro de los lineamientos de conducta, pero podría utilizar alguna ayuda de edición para mejorar la gramática, la ortografía o el formato.
  - **Comentar** para señalar el contenido que falta o que puede necesitar ajustes. Estos comentarios pueden ser útiles tanto para el autor de la publicación como para otros revisores.
  - **Reportar** publicaciones que son contenido no deseado o abusivas, así como las respuestas que no intentan responder a la pregunta o son sólo de enlace.
  - Los [Usuarios de confianza](/help/privileges/trusted-user) también pueden **Eliminar** las respuestas que no intentan responder a la pregunta, que son sólo de enlace o que son duplicados de otras respuestas.
- **Omitir** si no estás seguro de qué hacer.

### Respuestas tardías comunes

- Contenido no deseado o autopromoción

  - Si la respuesta cumple con la [descripción de autopromoción admisible](/help/promotion), agrega un comentario mencionando esto para reducir la chance de que otros revisores lo marquen como contenido no deseado. Si no lo cumple, agrega un comentario enlazando al artículo del centro de ayuda y anima al autor a editar la publicación para que cumpla nuestras pautas de conducta. Si inequívocamente luce como contenido no deseado, repórtalo como tal.
- No son respuestas

  - Son las respuestas agradeciendo al autor de la pregunta o de alguna de las respuestas, formulando una nueva pregunta, indicando que tienen el mismo problema, o pidiendo una aclaración al autor. Ellas deben ser eliminadas.

Para más información acerca de cómo editar eficazmente, por favor mira nuestro [artículo del Centro de Ayuda sobre la edición](/help/editing).

Parte del contenido de esta página se adapta a partir de la información de nuestra [página de preguntas frecuentes (FAQ) de Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180031), la cual también contiene una guía a mayor profundidad si estás interesado en leer más acerca de esta cola.

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I use the First answers queue?

---

*Access earned at $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues*

The First answers queue contains the first few answers created by new users, who may not fully understand the best way to answer questions. The purpose of this queue is to give special attention to users who may need to be educated on some aspect of our model, and to answers that are more likely to need improvement.

### Basic workflow

- Choose **Looks OK** if the post requires no intervention.
- Select **Edit** (or suggest an edit) if the post is clear and within guidelines but could use some editing help to improve grammar, spelling, or formatting.
- **Share feedback** if the post has the potential of being a good answer, but cannot be improved by anyone but the post-author. Choose from the standardized responses or leave a custom comment. You can post standardized comments as the Community bot or post as yourself and receive notifications.
- Choose **Other action** if the post needs to be flagged or requires a combination of interactions.
- **Skip** if you’re unsure about what to do.

One review from a user is enough to dismiss the task so review carefully to ensure that this question meets site expectations. Here are some guidelines when reviewing and deciding which actions to take on new posts:

- Check that the post author attempts to provide a focused answer, and not a simple comment or new question.
- Review the “Other answers” tab (if it exists) to confirm that the answer is unique from other answers provided.
- The post should not have broken links or be exclusively made up of links.
- If the post is spam or contains undisclosed promotional links, flag it as "spam".
- If the post is offensive, flag it as "rude or abusive".

For more information on how to edit effectively, please see our [Help Center article about editing](/help/editing).

## Traducción

#### ¿Cómo utilizo la cola de Primeras respuestas?

---

*Acceso ganado con una reputación de $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues*

La cola de Primeras respuestas contiene las primeras respuestas creadas por nuevos usuarios, que puede que no entiendan del todo la mejor manera de responder preguntas. El propósito de esta cola es prestar especial atención a los usuarios que puedan necesitar ser educados en algún aspecto de nuestro modelo, y a las respuestas que puede que necesiten mejoras.

### Flujo básico de trabajo

- Elige **Se ve bien** si la publicación no requiere intervención.
- Selecciona **Editar** (o sugiere una edición) si la publicación es clara y está dentro de las pautas pero podría necesitar ayuda de edición para mejorar la gramática, la ortografía o el formato.
- **Dejar un comentario** si la publicación tiene el potencial de ser una buena respuesta, pero no puede ser mejorada por nadie más que el autor de la publicación. Elige entre las respuestas estandarizadas o deja un comentario personalizado. Puedes dejar comentarios estandarizados como el bot Comunidad o comentar como tú mismo y recibir notificaciones.
- Elige **Otra acción** si la publicación necesita ser reportada o requiere una combinación de interacciones.
- **Omitir** si no estás seguro de qué hacer.

Una revisión de un usuario es suficiente para descartar la tarea, así que haz la revisión cuidadosamente para asegurarte de que esta respuesta<sup>1</sup> cumple con las expectativas del sitio. Estas son algunas pautas al momento de revisar y decidir qué acciones tomar en las nuevas publicaciones:

- Comprueba que el autor de la publicación intenta dar una respuesta concreta, y no un simple comentario o una nueva pregunta.
- Revisa la pestaña “Otras respuestas” (si existe) para confirmar que la respuesta es única con respecto a otras respuestas proporcionadas.
- La publicación no debe contar con enlaces rotos ni estar compuesto exclusivamente por enlaces.
- Si la publicación es contenido no deseado o contiene enlaces promocionales sin divulgación, repórtala como "contenido no deseado".
- Si la publicación es ofensiva, repórtala como "irrespetuoso o abusivo".

Para obtener más información sobre cómo editar eficazmente, consulta nuestro [artículo del Centro de Ayuda acerca de las ediciones](/help/editing).

---

> <sup>1</sup> En el texto original dice *question* (pregunta), pero es *answer* (respuesta) (según se ve [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-answers)).

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I use the First questions queue?

---

*Access earned at $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues reputation*

The First questions queue contains the first few questions created by new users, who may not fully understand the best way to ask questions, or what's on- and off-topic on this site. The purpose of this queue is to give special attention to users who may need to be educated on some aspect of our model, and to questions that are more likely to need improvement.

### Basic workflow

- Choose **Looks OK** if the post requires no intervention.
- Select **Edit** (or suggest an edit) if the post is clear and within guidelines but could use some editing help to improve grammar, spelling, or formatting.
- **Share feedback** if the post has the potential of being a good answer, but cannot be improved by anyone but the post-author. Choose from the standardized responses or leave a custom comment. You can post standardized comments as the Community bot or post as yourself and receive notifications.
- Choose **Other action** if the post needs to be flagged or requires a combination of interactions.
- **Skip** if you’re unsure about what to do.

One review from a user is enough to dismiss the task so review carefully to ensure that this question meets site expectations. Here are some guidelines when reviewing and deciding which actions to take on new posts:

- Check that the main part of the question is in the post itself and not hosted off-site. If there are links to other sites, the question should be written so that it makes sense even if the links break or change.
- The question should:

  - be clear
  - have all necessary information required to answer it
  - be on-topic for the site
  - solicit fact-based answers
  - show research
  - be appropriately tagged.
- If appropriate, leave a detailed comment and ask for the missing information to narrow the scope of the question, or reword the question so it fits the site scope.
- If the question seems like a question you have seen before, check if the post is a duplicate.
- Upvote good, well-written questions to encourage new users.
- If the post is spam or contains promotional links, flag it as "spam".
- If the post is offensive, flag it as "rude or abusive".
- Sometimes a question will need to be closed, which can be done by [flagging](/help/privileges/flag-posts) or voting to close it. You can read more about when questions should be closed [here](/help/closed-questions).

For more information on how to edit effectively, please see our [Help Center article about editing](/help/editing).

## Traducción

#### ¿Cómo utilizo la cola de Primeras preguntas?

---

*Acceso ganado con una reputación de $Privilege-AccessReviewQueues*

La cola de Primeras preguntas contiene las primeras preguntas creadas por nuevos usuarios, que puede que no entiendan del todo la mejor manera de hacer preguntas, o lo que está o no en la temática de este sitio. El propósito de esta cola es prestar especial atención a los usuarios que puedan necesitar ser educados en algún aspecto de nuestro modelo, y a las preguntas que puede que necesiten mejoras.

### Flujo básico de trabajo

- Elige **Se ve bien** si la publicación no requiere intervención.
- Selecciona **Editar** (o sugiere una edición) si la publicación es clara y está dentro de las pautas pero podría necesitar ayuda de edición para mejorar la gramática, la ortografía o el formato.
- **Dejar un comentario** si la publicación tiene el potencial de ser una buena pregunta<sup>1</sup>, pero no puede ser mejorada por nadie más que el autor de la publicación. Elige entre las respuestas estandarizadas o deja un comentario personalizado. Puedes dejar comentarios estandarizados como el bot Comunidad o comentar como tú mismo y recibir notificaciones.
- Elige **Otra acción** si la publicación necesita ser reportada o requiere una combinación de interacciones.
- **Omitir** si no estás seguro de qué hacer.

Una revisión de un usuario es suficiente para descartar la tarea, así que haz la revisión cuidadosamente para asegurarte de que esta pregunta cumple con las expectativas del sitio. Estas son algunas pautas al momento de revisar y decidir qué acciones tomar en las nuevas publicaciones:

- Comprueba que la parte fundamental de la pregunta está en la propia publicación y no alojada fuera del sitio. Si hay enlaces a otros sitios, la pregunta debe estar redactada de tal manera que tenga sentido incluso si los enlaces se rompen o cambian.
- La pregunta debe...

  - ...ser clara
  - ...tener toda la información necesaria requerida para responderla
  - ...estar en la temática del sitio
  - ...solicitar respuestas basadas en hechos
  - ...mostrar investigación
  - ...estar etiquetada apropiadamente.
- De ser apropiado, deja un comentario detallado y pide la información que falta para limitar el alcance de la pregunta, o pide reformular la pregunta para que se ajuste al ámbito del sitio.
- Si la pregunta se parece a una que ya has visto antes, comprueba si la publicación es un duplicado.
- Vota a favor las preguntas buenas y bien redactadas para animar a los nuevos usuarios.
- Si la publicación es contenido no deseado o contiene enlaces promocionales, repórtala como "contenido no deseado".
- Si la publicación es ofensiva, repórtala como "irrespetuoso o abusivo".
- A veces una pregunta necesitará ser cerrada, lo cual puede hacerse [reportándola](/help/privileges/flag-posts) o votando para cerrarla. Puedes leer más acerca de cuándo deben cerrarse las preguntas [aquí](/help/closed-questions).

Para obtener más información sobre cómo editar eficazmente, consulta nuestro [artículo del Centro de Ayuda acerca de las ediciones](/help/editing).

---

> <sup>1</sup> En el texto original dice *answer* (respuesta), pero es *question* (pregunta) (según se ve [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-questions)).

Comment: Está pendiente convertir las respuestas a CW :)