# ¿Por qué los artículos del centro de ayuda todavía no están traducidos?

Tags: soporte, traducciones, centro-de-ayuda

Sé que hay preguntas en meta con el objetivo de traducirlos como [este](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4938/169744).

Pero hay traducciones que llevan tiempo sugeridas como [esta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5344/169744) que todavía no se ven reflejadas en el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/review-queues).

¿Saben algo al respecto?

Comment: Y mirá que algunas todavía no se tradujeron... En esas respuestas no colaboré porque aún no tengo los privilegios suficientes para esas colas, entonces desconozco cómo se ven :)

Comment: Probablemente teniamos que avisarle al CM que ya estaban traducidas...